# SQL Don't Understand the Algorithm of IN Clause

Tags: mysql

Let's say you have an employee table and a department table and you need to find the highest salary in each department.

I know what IN clause is, but not for this particular code.

Why do we use

```
WHERE (Employee.DepartmentId, Salary) IN
FROM Employee
```

How do you translate in plain?

- List Department, Employee, Salary from those two tables that has the highest salary in each department? (because it's using group by?)

Then how come we don't just use in the beginning of select statement as max(salary)? write group by and order by in the end rather than writing IN Clause?

```
SELECT
    Department.name AS 'Department',
    Employee.name AS 'Employee',
    Salary
FROM
    Employee
        JOIN
    Department ON Employee.DepartmentId = Department.Id
WHERE
    (Employee.DepartmentId , Salary) IN
    (   SELECT
            DepartmentId, MAX(Salary)
        FROM
            Employee
        GROUP BY DepartmentId
    )
```

Comment: Hi slayers, please don't vandalize your posts, ask a Mod If there ist a urgent reason to remove your post just use flags with personal reasion in case of.

Comment: @slayers: rather than vandalizing your post you can delete it, using the `delete` button just below the tags.

Comment: @slayers Because it's not your question anymore, it belongs to the community. Have you read the contract when you joined SO?

Comment: @slayers bummi and Bob Jarvis made the assumption that you wanted to delete your post, possibly because you changed its body to contain just the word "delete" repeatedly. The comments they gave were a polite way to notify you of the correct way to delete a question. Please be nice.

Answer (score 1):

An expression like `WHERE (x,y) IN` makes sense if you are comparing it to 2 other values, such as:

```
WHERE (x, y) IN ((a,b), (x,y))
```

Would equal true.

The right-side of the IN clause can be replaced with a subquery.

So your example

```
(Employee.DepartmentId , Salary) IN
( SELECT DepartmentId, MAX(Salary) FROM Employee GROUP BY DepartmentId )
```

Means that this will match if the employees salary exactly matches the maximum salary for the department the employee is in. Basically implying that this query will select all highest earners in each department.

You're right that it's possible to rewrite this as a subquery in the "fields" clause or even as a join (my preference).

As for pros and cons. A lot of it has to do with habit and style. People tend to re-use patterns they are used to, and perhaps the author thought that this was the most legible solution.

Another reason might be how fast the query is. You can measure this yourself. Some queries are easier to optimize by mysql than others. For a long time all MySQL subqueries were very slow.

Comment: In my experience, MySQL often uses a very suboptimal query plan for `WHERE column in (subquery)`, and gets it right when you do it as a join.

Comment: Nice clarification and explanation of people's styling preferences... one not always the "best" way, just how they are used to writing queries.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Now it makes sense. It had to do more with MySQL style. You said your preference was join, how would you rewrite in your style?

Answer (score 1):

It is more simple with a nested query:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(Salary), Department 
  FROM(
    SELECT 
      Department.name AS 'Department', 
      Employee.name AS 'Employee', Salary 
    FROM Employee 
    JOIN Department 
    ON Employee.DepartmentId = mentId
  ) 
  AS table
  GROUP BY Employee.DepartmentId
```

Comment: @zx485 Thanks for your edit. I wrote it from tablet !